# Choosing the proper C# Project (Active Directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have recently started an internship in a big company (4.5k employees) which uses an Active Directory and have an intranet web app allowing them to handle all types of services, going from administration to user creation etc ... It was developped in 2004 and now they want to remake the whole application, well actually I have to make it. And kind of on my own, I am the only developer here. 
I was thinking of developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 project to develop this application, do you think that is a good choice? Don't know many other design-patterns for this, and I found on the web that Active Directory is accessible using ASP.NET MVC, and everything seems compatible. The old project used a hand made architecture, which didn't respect any design-pattern and using mainly VBScript. I want to use C#, that's the only imperative I guess.

Thanks for your help, I hope this is clear, if not I will try to make it clearer :D

Comment: You should separate your application into layers, putting your logic and other services in separate dlls, that way you can put whatever user interface you want on it without too much trouble whether it be MVC, Winforms, WPF or whatever

Comment: Ok thanks, will look into that (don't know much about dlls), do you mean logic and service should be in a different place that MVC, for the reasons you explained?

Comment: Yes, it's called separation of concerns.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658124.aspx

You can google around and find tons of articles and tutorials.  good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP .Net MVC seems to be a good choice. You can use ADAL for authentication and manage any kind of AD data. Here are some links:
[Http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm](http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm)

But you must master ASP.Net MVC (Bootstrap / razor / ...)

Good luck !

Comment: Alright thank you! Yes, a lot of working heading my way hah, good experience!

Comment: You know the secret now ... a lot of effort, and the Stackoverflow community. Welcome among us ;)

Comment: Of course. Right now I'm on stackoverflow, there's a good chance we'll meet. ;)